# O "campus universitário" ou o "câmpus universitário"?

Tags: ortografia, estrangeirismos, concordância

A palavra *campus* vem do *latim* e é utilizada para identificar universidades ou institutos federais de educação.

No *latim*: o *campus* / os *campi*

ou

Em português: o câmpus / os câmpus

Qual a forma mais correta de emprega-la?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A única forma correta em [Portugal](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/campus) é **campus** universitário.

A investigação mais profunda do Denis Henrique Caixeta ([esta parte é crédito dele](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/553/84)) leva a crer que no Brasil, embora não havendo consenso total, dá-se também preferência a [**câmpus**](http://unesp.br/aci_ses/conteudo.php?conteudo=1364).

---

The only correct form in [Portugal](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/campus) is (college/university) **campus**.

A more thorough research made by Denis Henrique Caixeta ([credit goes to him for this part](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/553/84)) reveals that in Brazil, although not having full consensus, [**câmpus**](http://unesp.br/aci_ses/conteudo.php?conteudo=1364) is also a word preferred by many.

Answer (score 5):

Os dicionários colocam a palavra *campus* para singular e *campi* para plural, ou seja, mantendo a forma original em *latim*. Não utiliza o acento circunflexo.

No entanto, fiz uma pesquisa sobre o assunto e verifique que no Brasil a palavra câmpus vem sendo utilizada pelos Institutos Federais e Universidades após nota lexicológica do Ministério da Educação. A seguir algumas citações sobre o assunto:

> 1) O Vocabulário ortográfico da língua portuguesa , da Academia Brasileira de Letras (4 ed. 2004), que é o registro oficial das palavras do português do Brasil, não registra campus nem campus nem câmpus.
>
> 2) O Dicionário Aurélio – Século XXI coloca a entrada “campus” sem acento, sem itálico, e com a indicação (uma flecha) de que se trata de estrangeirismo. Quanto à etimologia, indica: [ Lat ., pelo ingl . amer .]. Registra como plural: “ campi ( lat .)”. Não há exemplos.
>
> 3) O Dicionário Houaiss coloca a entrada “ campus ” (em itálico), sem acento. Quanto à etimologia, indica [ lat .], e, mais adiante, especifica: “ campus nom. sing . de campus, i ”. Para o plural, registra: “ campi ( lat .)”. Não há exemplos.
>
> 4) O jornal O Estado de S. Paulo usa sempre câmpus (com acento, como recomenda seu Manual de Redação), enquanto o jornal Folha de S. Paulo usa, em geral, campus (sem acento): no site da Folha de S. Paulo , entre 2000 e 2007 encontrei, em 2404 ocorrências, apenas 3 casos de câmpus , com acento). (NEVES, 2015)
>
> Indicações conclusivas:
>   1) Câmpus é um termo latino trazido à língua portuguesa para aplicação a um campo de especialidade, mas, pela própria acepção, tornou-se termo corrente, o que faz esperar sua incorporação à norma gráfica da língua.
>   2) Como forma de origem latina, essa palavra tem naturalmente a feição de palavra portuguesa, e facilmente se coloca entre outras semelhantes no rol de substantivos da língua.(NEVES, 2015)

Ainda conforme Faulstich, 2011 o uso da palavra câmpus para o singular e plural está de acordo com a gramática moderna.

> Em português, o uso do termo câmpus para o singular e para o plural
>   está perfeitamente de acordo com os cânones da gramática moderna, 
>   porque: i) a palavra já está incorporada ao vernáculo; ii) o acento
>   (circunflexo) em câmpus está no mesmo paradigma de outras palavras
>   terminadas em –us; no plural, câmpus mantém o mesmo modelo de
>   vírus, bônus, cítrus/citros etc. com marca nos determinantes – os
>   campus, os vírus, os bônus, os citros.
>   Portanto, a adoção da palavra câmpus para uso tanto no singular
>   quanto o plural está conforme com o uso gramatical do português.

Referências

FAULSTICH, Enilde. NOTA LEXICOLÓGICA: Câmpus, campus, campi? Disponível em:
http://ifc.edu.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/campus-campi-c%C3%A2mpus-Atualizado-2014.pdf. Acesso em: 20 de julho de 2015.

NEVES, Maria Helena de Moura. Padronizações - Sobre câmpus / campi. Disponível em :http://unesp.br/aci_ses/conteudo.php?conteudo=1364. Acesso em: 20 de julho de 2015.

Comment: Porém o Vocabulário Ortográfico já incluiu a palavra, sem o circunflexo, com a marca de que é estrangeira e vem do latim. O plural *campi* ainda não consta do VOLP.

Comment: +1, parece ser um daqueles casos manhosos em que nem todas as entidades brasileiras estão de acordo, mas o assunto está bem investigado.

Comment: Sim, é uma caso manhoso que resistem as mudanças e modernização, onde não há unaniminidade de opinião.  No final tente a aceitação do estrangeirismo com aportuguesamento e incorporação da palavra na língua portuguesa, neste caso com acento.  O  Brasil aceita muito bem o estrangeirismo com aportuguesamento, palavras como abajur, ateliê, baguete, bangalô e basquetebol foram aceita e tiveram sua grafia alterada.